# If both cells match return correct but ignore if both cells are zero?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Currently using =IF(D62=E62,"Stock correct",D62-E62) But When both cells are 0 How do I return blank?

Comment: `=IF(D62=0,"",IF(D62=E62,"Stock correct",D62-E62))`

Answer (score 1):

You can put nested `IF` condition, using `AND` logic.

```
=IF(AND(D62=0,E62=0),"blank",IF(D62=E62,"Stock correct",D62-E62)
```